# How to dynamically set the width of background icon in Angular

Tags: css, angular

Below is my style class to place an icon and a dynamic sized text on it.

```
new Style({                                                                                                
    zIndex: zIndexValue,                                                                                   
    image: new Icon(({                                                                                     
        src: './webapp/assets/images/image.svg',      
        anchor: [0.5,0.9],                                                                                                                                                                  
        zIndex: zIndexValue                                                                                
    })),                                                                                                   

    text: new Text({                                                                                       
        text: name,                                                                      
        offsetY: -21,                                                                                      
        offsetX: 10,                                                                   
        font: 'bold 10px sans-serif',                                                                      
        fill: new Fill({                                                                                   
            color: 'white'                                                                                 
        }),                                                                                                                                                                                            
        zIndex: zIndexValue       
    }) 
})
```

I want the svg file width to be adjusted according to the length of the text, means if it's a long text the svg file width should stretch enough to cover the entire text background. If small the background svg should be small as well. I am using angular 9

svg code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="134px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 134 50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>vehicle-location</title>
    <defs>
        <filter x="-8.9%" y="-30.9%" width="117.8%" height="161.8%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="filter-1">
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.376470588   0 0 0 0 0.42745098   0 0 0 0 0.556862745  0 0 0 0.5 0" type="matrix" in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
        <path d="M103,0 C111.284271,-1.52179594e-15 118,6.71572875 118,15 C118,23.2842712 111.284271,30 103,30 L62.654,30 L58.7929688,34 L54.931,30 L15,30 C6.71572875,30 1.01453063e-15,23.2842712 0,15 C-1.01453063e-15,6.71572875 6.71572875,1.52179594e-15 15,0 L103,0 Z" id="path-2"></path>
        <path d="M103,0 C111.284271,-1.52179594e-15 118,6.71572875 118,15 C118,23.2842712 111.284271,30 103,30 L62.654,30 L58.7929688,34 L54.931,30 L15,30 C6.71572875,30 1.01453063e-15,23.2842712 0,15 C-1.01453063e-15,6.71572875 6.71572875,1.52179594e-15 15,0 L103,0 Z" id="path-4"></path>
    </defs>
    <g id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="buttons/map/vehicle-location" transform="translate(3.000000, 4.000000)">
            <g id="vehicle-location" filter="url(#filter-1)" transform="translate(5.000000, 4.000000)">
                <mask id="mask-3" fill="white">
                    <use xlink:href="#path-2"></use>
                </mask>
                <path stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" d="M103,1 L15,1 C11.1340068,1 7.63400675,2.56700338 5.10050506,5.10050506 C2.56700338,7.63400675 1,11.1340068 1,15 C1,18.8659932 2.56700338,22.3659932 5.10050506,24.8994949 C7.63400675,27.4329966 11.1340068,29 15,29 L55.3555348,29 L58.7928814,32.5602013 L62.2293936,29 L103,29 C106.865993,29 110.365993,27.4329966 112.899495,24.8994949 C115.432997,22.3659932 117,18.8659932 117,15 C117,11.1340068 115.432997,7.63400675 112.899495,5.10050506 C110.365993,2.56700338 106.865993,1 103,1 Z"></path>
                <g id="Grey---90%" mask="url(#mask-3)" fill="#32436E">
                    <g transform="translate(-5.000000, -4.000000)" id="Bluish-Grey">
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="128" height="42"></rect>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <mask id="mask-5" fill="white">
                    <use xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                </mask>
                <path stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" d="M103,1 L15,1 C11.1340068,1 7.63400675,2.56700338 5.10050506,5.10050506 C2.56700338,7.63400675 1,11.1340068 1,15 C1,18.8659932 2.56700338,22.3659932 5.10050506,24.8994949 C7.63400675,27.4329966 11.1340068,29 15,29 L55.3555348,29 L58.7928814,32.5602013 L62.2293936,29 L103,29 C106.865993,29 110.365993,27.4329966 112.899495,24.8994949 C115.432997,22.3659932 117,18.8659932 117,15 C117,11.1340068 115.432997,7.63400675 112.899495,5.10050506 C110.365993,2.56700338 106.865993,1 103,1 Z"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you share the SVG code? Or maybe make a visual representation?

Comment: @ArnoTenkink I have added the SVG code.